# Start pdflatex in C#

Tags: c#, process

What can I use to start pdflatex from a C# application? A textbox covers some tex code and it should be transformed into a pdf without the Windows command box.

Comment: Please include a sample of the code you've tried, along with details of why it's not working for you.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie It seems that he/she does not have any code till yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna start a process (e.g. `pdflatex.exe`), then you could use the `Process` class.

[msdn Process.Start method with a concrete example how to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)